# how to use getHSBColor() in android Color or android Paint?

Tags: java, android, colors

I am trying to push following method onto android:

On my PC-version I got a color which keeps changing it's hue:

(The update method gets repeatedly called every 5ms or so):

```
int hue = 0;    
Color color;

public void update() {
    hue += 0.0125;
    color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1, 1);
}
```

This method gives returns me a color permanently changing its color.

I would like to use this method on android, too, but there I am missing the Color.getHSBColor() feature... Any ideas how to change the hue of an android color?

In addition to this question: How can I apply this color to my paint? paint.setColor() requires an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the static methods of Android's `android.graphics.Color` class. They will return an int which you can use as the color in paint.setColor():

```
   paint.setColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsv)); //hsv is the a float[] with hsv color values
```

The the hsv[0] would be the Hue value, see [Color.HSVtoColor documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#HSVToColor%28float%5B%5D%29)

> hsv[0] is Hue [0 .. 360) hsv[1] is Saturation [0...1] hsv[2] is Value [0...1]

Comment: Yes it did, thanks! Sorry forgot to click on this button

Comment: Sorry, but I thought HSV and HSB is not the same thing?